# SlideToggle and Microsoft Edge

Tags: jquery, microsoft-edge

I am using jQuery's `.slideToggle()` and it works with all browsers except Microsoft Edge.

The code is `$("#elementname").slideToggle();`

Comment: Please improve your question by adding some details. Tell us what version of Jquery and Edge you're using and provide a complete example that can be verified.

Comment: I've tested on build 10586 (Edge 13, from November 2015), and build 14390 (Edge 14, recent Insider build), and both seem work with regards to jQuery's `$.fn.slideToggle` method. I suspect your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Would you believe that it started to work if I do not get it to default?

like so:

$("#elementname").slideToggle(400);

So, I am leave this answer here to help others out.